# Flash Video Loading Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flash

Please click on the below link

```
http://hpecp.vmokshagroup.com/videobook/html/homepage.html
```

When we click on "What is VideoBook" link we got some blank screen before starting the swf file due to video fetching from the server. We have to avoid blank screen.

We are facing a problem of fetching the video clips from the hosting server. I added two video clips in Flash (.swf)... one is from the beginning, another one is at the ending and in between some text animations.

While we are playing/calling .swf file in browser from hosting server, initially getting blank screen. It takes some time to fetching the video clip from server due to size. Starting of first video clip duration is about 3-6 seconds. While video is being loaded.. text animation is starting without playing first video clip. Same problem we are facing in second video at the ending.

Is there any option to incorporate video clips internally in Flash (.swf file) rather than calling from external server or external file path?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the JavaScript that you use - it actually makes the swf files (in)visible depending on the situation. What this does is that it actually loads the .swf files each time. You can check that in the Network tab of your debugger (I'm using Chrome).

So it first loads Video-01d.swf, or Video-02.swf. They take time to load, and just when the main file is loaded, it starts to load the video file (video1.flv).

All that causes delay, and it's pretty normal as you have all that things in separate files. If you want to, you can merge them into one - just import the flv inside your .swf file and it will work out well..

Of course, you will need to change all your logic for the flash files that you are playing. You will also need to change the JavaScript to call Flash functions in order to tell it to go to another "scene".

I will advise you to add a simple gif loader image (like [this](http://preloaders.net/)), put it as a background-image of the div, and put some color into that div. What the user will see is that the movie disappears, there is a black background with a loading symbol inside, and then the new video begins. It's a normal thing to see online - preloaders :) Good luck!